# Is it possible to put read-only text inside input alongside writable text?

Tags: html

I want to make an input with some read-only text and some writable text. It should always say "www." at the beginning (read only) and afterwards the user should be able to write whatever he wants. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "*easiest*" way would be to have a separate element underneath (or surrounding) the `input`.

http://jsfiddle.net/NxWBT/

However, this'll be for presentational purposes only. If you need the `www` part submitted, you'll have to add it with Javascript before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

On KeyDown event you can get the string an append it

```
function onblurwww(){
    var tb = document.getElementById('myTextBox');
    var val = tb.value;

    if (val.substr(0, 4) != 'www.')
        tb.value = 'www.' + val;
}
```

something like that in your keydown on the textbox.

Comment: 1) You're adding `www.` **every single time** a key is pressed. 2) This will always move the cursor to the end of the string. If the user goes back to the middle of the string and starts typing, all the letters from the second character and on, will be placed at the end of the string.

Comment: Very true. You could use onblur instead so that only when the textbox was exited would the www be appended. Or try Joseph Silber's fiddle below, that works well.

Comment: But you're still adding `www.` every time the user blurs away. You'll have to run a regEx (or `substr`) before adding to that value, to ascertain that it does not yet have `www.` at the beginning of it. IMHO, my answer is much more efficient...

Comment: Well its a quick answer, obviously needs refining and I did already recommend your answer...

Comment: That's not the point here. We don't want to have false advice sitting here for future generations... I edited your answer.